# ICC assembly line number

Tags: c++, assembly

I am using the Intel Compiler (icl.exe) on Windows. I let the compiler print the line information of the instructions. Normally the line number matches the source file I passed to the compiler. In some cases it adds instructions generated by some header files I included. But which file is it?

```
$LN10:
    mov       rax, 0d4b249ad2594c37dH     #45.20   line from which file?
$LN11:
    mulsd     xmm0, xmm0                  #7.3     matches the expected source file
```

MSVC on the other hand prints out the filename of the header where this instruction comes from. How can I get this information also in ICC?

```
# File d:\...\base.h
# Line 48
$LN3:
    movsdx  QWORD PTR [rsp+16], xmm1
```

**Update**:

On Linux it seems ICC prints out some more information. The *.file* directive is added there.

```
..LN1:
   .file   2 "/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h"
   .loc    2  82  is_stmt 1
        xor       eax, eax                                      #82.2
   [...]
   .loc    1  5  is_stmt 1
        ret                                                     #5.3                                               #5.3
```

Comment: Aren't there any directives / comments between instructions?

Comment: There is just a label between the instructions which does not seem to refer to anything. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What version of intel's compiler are you using?  I made a small test with some code in a header and found that invoking icl.exe with the `/FAcs` option makes intel's compiler generate the .cod file with included file information per line (as you would expect).  The toolset I'm using is Intel C++ Compiler 16.0

Comment: Brilliant! Can you please make this as an answer to earn the bounty? I just used /FA, obviously I missed /FAc and /FAs (/FAcs).